# While retrieving image and other information from database, it displays image only

Tags: sql, jsp, blob

My requirement is to insert artist details and his picture through jsp into oracle database and retrieve back information and picture through another jsp program.

`artist table` has five columns, four are `varchar2` and fifth column is `blob` type.

I have successfully inserted but facing problem in retrieving. Because it is only displaying image but no other information. Below is the code.

```
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from artist");
                ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){ %>
                <table><tr><th>artist fast name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td></tr> 
                    <tr><th>artist middle name:</th><td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>artist last name</th><td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>artist job</th><td><%=rs.getString(4) %></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>artist image</th><td><img src="
                <%
                    Blob bl=rs.getBlob(5);
                    byte[] image=bl.getBytes(1, (int)bl.length());
                    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                    OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                    o.write(image);
                    o.flush();
                    o.close();
             }
                %>" height="100" width="100" alt="bye"/> </td></tr>
                </table> 
                    <%
               con.close();
```

please suggest me to display complete info from table

Comment: Any errors in the console or stack traces ?

Comment: no there are no errors in console or stack traces....

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to retrieve other information on successful retrievation of blob from database using jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802040/unable-to-retrieve-other-information-on-successful-retrievation-of-blob-from-dat)